# Fluentd - Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, fluentd, efk

In an `EFK` setup, the `fluentd` suddenly stopped sending to `elasticsearch` with the following errors in the logs:

```
2020-09-28 18:48:55 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
2020-09-28 18:48:55 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 6. Retry to communicate after 512 second(s).
```

The `elasticsearch` components are up and running, and I can `curl` and access `elasticsearch` from inside the `fluentd` pod. There is no error message in the logs of the `elasticsearch`.

Restarting the `fluentd` pod or `elasticsearch` components did not help.

Answer (score -2):

The issue was in one of the configurations that was uploaded to `fluentd`. The `elasticsearch` host was set to a wrong value in that configuration. After fixing that configuration, the issue waa resolved.

Comment: Could you share what was wrong in the configuration and how you fixed it? I seem to have a same problem but cannot solve it.

Comment: it ludicrous not put out the actual solution for us to learn as well